# Google Search & Yahoo Pipes 503 Error

Tags: regex, rss, google-search, yahoo-pipes

I'm trying to run a Google news query through Yahoo Pipes, it produces a valid URL which I can still copy into the browser to get the code for an RSS feed, (so I know special characters are being translated correctly etc) but when Pipes tries to read the URL, more often than not it comes out with

```
This Pipe ran successfully but encountered some problems:
warning Error fetching 
https://news.google.com/news?hl=en&q= ...etc... output=rss.
Response: Service Unavailable (503)
```

The most annoying thing is that it works fine in local/console mode about half the time, so the URL is good, but it seems the search engine's server may not like these automated searches??

I don't know much about SQL, Regex or Pipes, any insight would be very helpful!

Comment: You need an Application ID for your project — problem solved. https://developer.apps.yahoo.com/wsregapp/

Comment: Oh right, thanks. Should I go for Browser Based Authentication?

Comment: If you're not going to use an SDK then you'll want BBAuth, or OAuth :)

Comment: Required access scopes? - Sorry, bit of a beginner.

Comment: Here's a guide you can go through, it will probably answer most of your concerns: https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-scopes.html. Go with OAuth, it's more versatile — I haven't used yahoo's API in a while and didn't realize they offered it.

Comment: Done all that now, then I created a project and registered my pipe as 'BBAuth URL', I also created a Project and made my pipe the 'Application URL' but nothing has changed?

Comment: Still error `503`? Usually that's an indication of an overloaded server, or under Maintenance. Don't forget they're probably scrambling to fix the OpenSSL exploit that their servers were found to have.

Comment: Have you managed to find a fix for this problem? I am encountering a similar problem and have no solution.

Comment: I think I needed a developers licence / application ID or something like that from Google, in order to allow my Pipe make automated calls to Google. More to to the point, how are you still able to use Pipes?